# Performing a COUNT on the MAX number of occurences

Tags: sql, oracle, count, max, aggregate

My scenario is that person A can sells product A each month of the year.  From that information I had to calculate in what month they sold the most of product A for the current year.

Should they sell 10 of product A in January, 6 in August and 10 October, i take the info for the latest month (in this case October).

However, i want to include some sort of tracker that says if the current MAX for the year has been equaled by person A at an earlier point in the year i want to COUNT the number of occurencies.  Should person A go on to sell 15 in Novemeber, the counter should restart.

Current data =

```
EMP         PRODUCT           MONTH         VOLUME
---------------------------------------------------
A            A                 1             10
A            A                 8             6
A            A                 10            10
```

AIM=

```
EMP         PRODUCT           MAX(VOLUME)    COUNT
---------------------------------------------------
A             A                    10           2
```

Any suggestions as to the most efficient way of resolving this would be great!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (EMP VARCHAR2(10), PRODUCT VARCHAR2(10), MONTH NUMBER, VOLUME NUMBER);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('A', 'A', 1, 10);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('A', 'A', 8, 6);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('A', 'A', 10, 10);

COMMIT;

--EMP         PRODUCT           MONTH         VOLUME
-----------------------------------------------------
--A            A                 1             10
--A            A                 8             6
--A            A                 10            10



SELECT EMP,
       PRODUCT,
       VOLUME,
       MY_COUNT
  FROM (  SELECT EMP,
                 PRODUCT,
                 VOLUME,
                 COUNT (MY_RANK) MY_COUNT,
                 RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EMP, PRODUCT ORDER BY VOLUME DESC)
                    MY_SECOND_RANK
            FROM (SELECT EMP,
                         PRODUCT,
                         volume,
                         RANK ()
                            OVER (PARTITION BY EMP, PRODUCT
                                  ORDER BY VOLUME DESC, MONTH DESC)
                            MY_RANK
                    FROM MY_TABLE)
        GROUP BY EMP, PRODUCT, VOLUME)
 WHERE MY_SECOND_RANK = 1;
```

Comment: Glad I could help! ;-)